# How to sort "category" data from object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, object

I am new here so I hope I will do everything correctly and understandable for you.

I have object like this:

```js
this.state = {
      commandersArray: {
        1: {
          name: "Horattio",
          amountOfPlanets: "120",
          rank: "Field-Marshal",
          equipment: "Strong",
          army: "190 123 122"
        },
        2: {
          name: "Tento",
          amountOfPlanets: "69",
          rank: "General",
          equipment: "Medium",
          army: "40 123 912"
        },
```

There is rank: inside of rank there are some army ranks values.
I made sorting for name alphabetically and then on amountofPlanets asc and desc. That's fine, but now i would like to have sorting as i personally wants, it means, the when i Click on some button for RANK sorting, i would like to have on  1) position Field-Marshal, 2) General 3) Captain 4)...

I understand that i need to somehow assign new value like for example `marshal === 1`, `general === 2`. 
I have idea but i don't know where to start and it looks like a bad solution add some another values to object for each item from object.

Thank you for advice, if you have any more questions or I did something wrong, I missed some information etc. let me know.

I tried to check related questions, but nothing was helpful for me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Nejtn! `commandersArray` is an object, and not an array. Are you sure you don't want it to be an array instead?

Comment: @Tholle what would be the best benefit, of course i should rename for better naming "commandersArray" to "commandersObject" but why should i change my Object to Array?

Comment: Having an object where the keys are just numerical indices indicate that an array would be a better data structure. Then you can sort, remove a certain element and all the other indices will still be correct, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could put the ranks in an array in the order you would want them in, and then check for the objects `rank` index in this array when you do the sorting.

**Example**

```js
const state = {
  commandersObject: {
    0: {
      name: "Foo",
      amountOfPlanets: "12",
      rank: "Captain",
      equipment: "Weak",
      army: "123 456 789"
    },
    1: {
      name: "Horattio",
      amountOfPlanets: "120",
      rank: "Field-Marshal",
      equipment: "Strong",
      army: "190 123 122"
    },
    2: {
      name: "Tento",
      amountOfPlanets: "69",
      rank: "General",
      equipment: "Medium",
      army: "40 123 912"
    }
  }
};
const rankOrder = ["Field-Marshal", "General", "Captain"];
const commandersArray = Object.keys(state.commandersObject)
  .map(key => state.commandersObject[key]);
  
commandersArray.sort((a, b) =>
  rankOrder.indexOf(a.rank) - rankOrder.indexOf(b.rank)
);

console.log(commandersArray);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just do `const commandersArray = Object.values(state.commandersObject);`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, you're right, but I tend not to use that in my answers since it has no IE support.

Comment: Use a [shim](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-object-values-entries/blob/master/polyfill.js).

Answer (score -3):

try to take the object and make it equal to your new value! from which you'll compare.

```
commandersArray.2.rank === "General"
```

try something like that!

Try bubble, selection or insertion sorting algorithm!